# PDF download button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am making a CV generator, and i need help. I am making a button, which will generate the CV as pdf and make it downloadable. Is there any way i can do it in HTML and CSS, not js and jquery?

```
<h3><a href="#" class="button dark ripple-effect button-sliding-icon" style="width: 154.609px;">Download PDF<i class="icon-feather-check"></i></a></h3>
```

[image: This is how it looks like, it should download the CV down below..]

Comment: "_Is there any way i can do it in HTML and CSS, not js and jquery?_". Do _what exactly_?
Generate and Download the PDF?

Comment: you could use convertapi.com - https://www.convertapi.com/web-to-pdf#snippet=html

Comment: @FabianS. yes..

Comment: @Coja you could add a print stylesheet, set the button to `javascript:window.print();` so i opens the print view. But i believe there is _no_ way to generate a PDF via HTML/CSS only as those languages do not offer any programming logic you would need to convert stuff.

Comment: @FabianS. thank you for your help, i will try with js then :) and i will also try what Stender sent too !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no HTML/CSS only way to actually generate a PDF.

However, you could use a print stylesheet (media print - see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and set your links href to `javascript:window.print();` to make it open the print dialog.

The user could use the "print to pdf" function (if the users PC offered that) to generate a PDF from the print view, but thats the closest youll get to actually generate a PDF in pure HTML/CSS i believe.